# div under another div

Tags: html, css

with css, can I put a div under another div without using absolute positioning?

I have these two divs, and I would like the solid white one to appear directly under the one with the yellow opacity (but not direct in the corner, at the corner of the outline).

How can this be accomplished. I've been experimenting with `z-index` and relative positioning, but to no avail.

Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/WtGsv/

Comment: Absolute positioning is the usual solution when you have two elements you want to appear in the same spot. Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: clarify as im seeing your fiddle as you request

Comment: @Quentin  well, I can't really absolute position because these elements (the divs I havd on the fiddle) will be created dynamically on the page. They won't always be in the same place :/

Comment: You just need to give them both a parent div (that wraps both) and set the parent div to `position:relative;` then it won't matter how it's dynamically created.

Comment: @Andy I added an example of your suggestion in my answer

Comment: @thomas I updated my answer too with an example of absolute positioning, alternatively click here for the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WtGsv/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using positioning, I added a style to your content div using negative margins:

```
.content {
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/WtGsv/3/

I suggest adding an id to your `.fixed_width` div which houses the `.content` div though, and using the id to give the negative margin to, that way the parent div has the negative margin, not the child div.

However if you want to use absolute positioning, I have updated your jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WtGsv/12/

Basically, you add a parent div with `position:relative;` around your other two divs that you want to use `position:absolute;`

Comment: This is a really comprehensive solution. Thank you so much, Andy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yuu can use `position:  relative; top -100px`, http://jsfiddle.net/WtGsv/1/

or you can use negative margins `margin-top: -100px` http://jsfiddle.net/WtGsv/5/

With both solutions, the div at the bottom still takes space where it would be originally

Note that adding a div dynamically doesn't preclude you from making it absolutely positioned, you just have to make the parent be positioned relative, and the dynamic absolutely positioned div will be inserted right where you want it http://jsfiddle.net/WtGsv/10/

Comment: Neat. Thanks! is this reliable in what browsers. I seem to recall having trouble with negative margins,  positions..like reacting different in different browsers. Is that wrong. Also, would you just use z-index to control their altitude, of is there some other way of controlling which is on top. Putting the div with the inputs about the yellow div seemed not to accomplish this. Thanks again!

Comment: @thomas you have to test it yourself in your target browsers, but it's reliable as far as I know. Yes, `z-index` is how you control the stacking of layers

Comment: @JuanMendes beat me to it for the example, but as you see the parent div positioned relative will still allow dynamic content.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, Juan. And all the examples!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should rewrite the markup, it is very simple, I don't know whether you are aware of this or not but you can pick up the div and place it in a `relative` positioned container, than you wont need negative margins

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WtGsv/9/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    Add a line item
    <div class="inner_wrap"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.wrap {
    border: 4px dashed #ff0000;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: relative;
}

.inner_wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #919191;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure I understand this fiddle. There appears to be only the one div. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @thomas You are not aware of CSS positioning, yes you can give **-** margins but you can avoid it, `absolute positioned div` can be floated inside `relative positioned div` so why use negative margins when you can accomplish this in a clean way

Answer (score 1):

You can place the div you want to be on top inside the div you want underneath, and position the one on top absolutely inside the parent.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="bottom">
    lorem ipsum

    <div id="top">
        hello world
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bottom {
    background:red; /* to see dimensions */
    position:relative;
}

#top {
    background:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3); /* only to prove that it's on top */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCRt5/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If you put them both inside a parent div, and set that to have a width equal on the width of the yellow box, then by default the white one would be placed directly below.

Answer (score 0):

I did this way

```css
.mainUnderline{
    height:8px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-top:-15px;
}   

.header{
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:30px;
    color:black;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 “See line under me”
  <div class="mainUnderline"></div>
</div>
```